# Get full HTML after Ajax requests

Tags: html, ajax

Using PHP, how can I get the full HTML for a page after all Ajax requests have been executed on that page?

Basically, I would like to have the same HTML you see when you inspect an element in Google Chrome showing both the original HTML plus the extra markup added after the Ajax calls are done.

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: isn't that what ajax do .. get the output of the url regardless what type of data it is ..

Comment: you'll get whatever the contents of your requesting page

Comment: copyedit question, remove php tag, shorten question

Comment: Once the html page loads there might be some ajax loading that gets more data to the page. In Chrome, when you press F12 to inspect an element, you will see the full html code of the page after any ajax requests fetched the additional data. This html code will be different from when you view the original source code of the same page (right-click and View page source). I want to get the full html code after the ajax requests are complete. Hope I was clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use a headless browser to render the page. Check out [Mink](https://github.com/minkphp/Mink), as it appears to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to Mink... looks nice...

However can Mink get the entire fetched page after the ajax requests are complete and save it as an html file on disk please? If you can provide an example, that would be great